# apt-get purge package does not delete!

Tags: server, package-management, php, debian, php7

I am trying to fully uninstall PHP. I tried apt-get purge php7.3. But after my installation, the folder in /etc/ is still there and filled with data. Why? I also did autoremove.

Comment: You mean `apt-get remove --purge <package>`?

Comment: You spelled `purge` wrong.

Comment: It should be **PURGE**  -  `apt-get purge php7.3`

Comment: PHP is split into many packages, so if you want to remove it completely you need to purge all of them. You can see them with `apt list --installed | grep php`.

Comment: Are you using Debian? If yes, unfortunately it's off-topic here.